# How to find the stability of time dependent Lyapunov equation?

Tags: covariance, stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, linearized-theory

After linearization of the nonlinear equations, I want to find the covariance matrix $v$ through the numerical solution of time dependent Lyapunov equation, $$dv/dt=a*v + v*a'+ d,$$ where $a$ is my system matrix ($a'$ is transpose) and $d$ is diffusion matrix (stochastic noise). The numerical solution of the mean equations is coupled to the linear equations that goes into system matrix a. But my Lyapunov solution for time range $t$ blows up, though the mean solution of nonlinear equations (including dampings) seems fine as oscillating around zero. I expect that the time dependent solution should decay starting from the initial condition, but it's not.  How can I test the stability of the system? does the solution of that equation itself gives me covariance or shall I use absolute values for the diagonal elements? Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: @Ghoster, I just edited.

Comment: Usually one would time-average over the Lyaponov exponent to get a criterion for stability (see the analysis of chaotic systems).

Comment: @JosBergervoet, thanks. Any relevant reference for that please.